# I want a function to be called only after live data is received

Tags: android, kotlin

i am using live data in android. But my problem is that the data is received at last after every function is called. In my case one of my function has dependency on live data but it is called before live data is received.i have added comments to make u understand better. Please help.

```
// polist is a MutableList
 transactionDao.selectAll().observe(this, Observer {
                if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
                   polist.addAll(it)
                }
            })
 vregularDao.getAll().observe(this, Observer {
                if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
                   polist.addAll(it)
                }
            })
// but this is called first then above codes.I want this to be called only after live data is received
 alllist.forEach{
         //perform some action   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into threads. The code below runs in a thread and once there's a return value it is added to `polist`

```
transactionDao.selectAll().observe(this, Observer {
                if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
                   polist.addAll(it)
                }
            })
```

Same for

```
 vregularDao.getAll().observe(this, Observer {
                if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
                   polist.addAll(it)
                }
            })
```

Therefor the last chunk of code is called directly. as the other two thread hasn't returned any data at the moment.

You would need to create some sort of blocker.

So it would be call another function after the list enumeration, this isn't elegant(PSUDEOCODE)...

```
    bool selectAllDone;
    bool getAllDone;
    // polist is a MutableList
 transactionDao.selectAll().observe(this, Observer {
                if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
                   polist.addAll(it)
                   performSomeAction();
                   selectAllDone = true;
                }
            })
 vregularDao.getAll().observe(this, Observer {
                if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
                   polist.addAll(it)
                   performSomeAction();
                   getAllDone = true;
                }
            })
    // but this is called first then above codes.I want this to be called only after live data is received
     public fun performSomeAction(){
if(getAllDone & selectAllDone){
     alllist.forEach{
             //perform some action   
            }  
}
}
```

Comment: Nice !! but this will not work in my case because one data may be null and in that case my fuction will never run. I wanted it to run even if one data is null. And btw i have 5 live data calls , i m showing only 2.

Comment: In that case remove the boolean checks. It will redo you `alllist.foreach` every time you get more data

Comment: This could be a good solution but i want that func to run only once

Comment: @NoobDev Then i dont think the function to get the data you are using is correct. When there is any change to the database that contains the data you are using your function would run.